# MySQL vs PostgreSQL spatial application

Tags: database, spatial

I need help in the choice of a DBMS to use in a spatial application (considering geometry data, and  not geography).

About you, which is better between MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you really wanna do, MySQL is user-friendly with all the UI tools it has, now you are able to model and create databases very fast with the mysql workbench. In terms of performance, MySQL is good, but I think Postegres has a better license and even when it has no a lot of tools, it provides the required functionality.

You can take a look at this: http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL

I recommend you this video as well:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PoFIohBSM4

Best regards my friend.

Comment: Since you work with numbers and math values, strongly recommend Postegres.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, I have to develop a solution wich exploits some geometric information (simply a position on a flat plane) to retrieve values of some features corresponding on a predefined position on a plane. Surely I won't need to use the full functionality of the openGIS spatial extension. So, do you suggest me to use PostgreeSQL?

Comment: YEs, better, if you want to work with that kind of information. PostgreSQL is a very useful database for what you're trying to do. MySQL still has some bugs wowking with numeric operations or values. I used PostegreSQL to develop an application that simulates a plane radar, I turned to it from mySQL since mySQL was having some problems when returning complex values or coordenates. Best regards and sorry for the late response.